# Como eliminar la carpeta que se crea con el nombre del proyecto para la copia de seguridad con laravel-backup

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10

Hola a todos estoy usando laravel-backup versión 8.5.1 para poder realizar la copias de seguridad en mi app de laravel, el caso es que al momento de hacer la copia de seguridad me crea una carpeta con el nombre de mi app. `APP_NAME=My_APP` y la ubicación de los archivos de copia de seguridad quedaría así: `storage/app/POS/My_APP/backup_2024-02-06-22-24-17.zip`

Quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de eliminarlo la carpeta My_APP y que los archivos de copia de seguridad se guarden dentro de la carpeta de POS quedando como resultado algo como esto `storage/app/POS/backup_2024-02-06-22-24-17.zip`

esto es mi disco en /config/filesystems.php

```
'disks' => [
        'POS' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/POS'),
        ],

    ],
```

Comment: vas al config/backup.php y cambias el disk ejemplo `'disks' => ['POS']`

Comment: Así lo tengo en config/backup pero sigue creándose la carpeta con el nombre de mi app.